# How to create inputs for my Indicator in MQL4?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, forex, mt4

Please, how can I create a txt file which my Custom Indicator can read, and where I can store, add and edit my inputs, I would want it to look exactly like this :

```
symbol;digits;M1;M5;M15;M30;H1;H4;D1;W1;MN
EURUSD;4;20;40;70;130;200;350;650;1200;3500
USDCAD;4;20;40;70;130;200;350;650;1200;3500
USDNZD;4;20;40;70;130;200;350;650;1200;3500
```

I would want to be in position of adding more lines of data(inputs)

I have tried to start coding it but failed

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How to create inputs for my Indicator in MQL4?"*

### Step 0:

Define the file-format. The file per-se has to be inside `<Terminal>/MQL4/files` plus inside `<Terminal>/Tester/files` so as to let it become readable for the MQL4-code. Se the documentation for details of this *sandboxing*.

### Step 1:

Define the file-reader **`void ConfigReader() {... }`** so as to match your file-format from Step-O.

### Step 2:

Call the **`ConfigReader()`** from inside the event-handling section **`OnInit()`**.

### Step 3:

Design the rest of the Custom-indicator so as to obey such file-parametrised, `OnInit`-read-in throughout its rest of the life-cycle.

### Step 4:

You are in the finish-line - THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED !

Comment: sir, please i ask that you ellaborate

Comment: @SsebaanaJoel And which particular Step of your above specified file-based configurator is not clear to design the right MQL4 implementation code? Next - what was the error logged in MQL4-code that you failed at resolving? *( yes, show the MQL4 code as-is and how it compiles / runs ... the logs ... )*

Comment: i was wondering how i could call trigger my EA with signals from my Custom Indicator